# Slow loading due to high number of layers

Tags: performance, plugins, qgis

The initial startup of QGIS takes a long time (about 3-4 minutes). I see problem with layers -- some layers are large and moreover in project there are a lot of layers. I found tool in **View --> Panels --> Debugging/Development --> Profiler --> Project Load** that some layers take a huge portion of time.

**What I need**

In my opinion, the most practical solution can be before starting menu see menu with all layers, where can I choose which layers, I need interact -- this can save time with *project loading*. This could be useful for this purpose because of there are plenty of people, which can need different layers to use.

Next solution can be creating templates, but for this purpose it is disadvantageous.

I tried searching plugin for this purpose, but I don't find anything useful.

Is there some plugin or feature in QGIS which can do that?

[QGIS Desktop 3.28.7]